# Impressão de Array de Strings em um único MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho uma variável que é um array de `string`s e eu quero imprimir seus valores, mas esse valores e consequentemente a quantidade deles só é definida após o sistema funcionar.

Como eu posso imprimir em uma `MessageBox`, por exemplo, todos os valores de todas as posições em apenas um `MessageBox` ao invés de fazer um `for` e imprimir uma por uma?

Comment: As posições de uma string são `char`s. É isto mesmo que você quer imprimir?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não são char, são string,                                   `string[] dataTransacao = null;`

Comment: Então é um vetor de `string`. [`string` é um vetor por definição (veja o 4o exemplo)](http://www.lucianopimenta.com/post.aspx?id=189). Vou colocar uma resposta pra você.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplesmente usa [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string.Join(", ", valores);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5nh3wo

Answer (score 3):

Outra opção seria a seguinte

```
var dataTransacao = new string[] {"01/01/2015", "02/02/2015", "03/03/2015" };
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Datas de transação: {0}", String.Join(", ", dataTransacao)), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

No exemplo abaixo a variável `strDados` contém todos os itens do *array* separados por vírgula.

```
string[] dados = { "um", "dois", "três" };
string strDados = string.Join(", ", dados);

MessageBox.Show(strDados);
```

O `MessageBox` mostrará:

> um, dois, três

Answer (score 1):

Você pode realizar esta impressão usando a função [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/Bb548651(v=VS.110).aspx). Por exemplo:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataTransacao.Aggregate( (acumulador, posicao) => acumulador + ", " + posicao, "Título"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Se você declarar `dataTransacao` assim:

```
var dataTransacao = new string[] {"01/01/2015", "02/02/2015", "03/03/2015" };
```

Vai sair na `MessageBox` assim:

```
01/01/2015, 02/02/2015, 03/03/2015
```